# How to check if the difference between two timestamps(2) is bigger than five minutes or five seconds in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

So far I'm doing something like this:

```
SELECT (EXTRACT(SECOND FROM (timeend  - timebeg))) AS diff 
FROM sometable HAVING diff > 5;
```

But it's not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't use aliases of fields from `select` clause in `where`

```
SELECT EXTRACT(second FROM (timeend  - timebeg)) AS diff 
FROM sometable 
WHERE EXTRACT(second FROM (timeend  - timebeg))> 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select ((enddate - startdate) * 24 * 60 * 60 ) as diff 
from table_name;
```

This gives the diff in seconds and you can further filter your query based off that.

Comment: Except... The brother has timestamp fields, not dates??

Comment: yes you are right..something like this will work instead select (CAST( endtimestamp AS DATE ) - CAST(starttimestamp AS DATE ) ) * 24*60*60 from table

Comment: It will not work in all cases, due to rounding: 12:00:05.333 vs 12:00:00.000 is greater than 5 seconds, but becomes = 5 seconds after cast to date. Adam already provided the correct solution.

Comment: Didnt realize that it rounds to seconds and does not do fractional